# How to parse HTML that changes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, html-parsing

I am trying to get parse an HTML doc here: https://www.producthunt.com/tech/travelisty-2-0.

You'll see next to the blue "Get It" button, there are icons of peoples. If you click on that there are numerous twitter handles. When I inspect element, I see only 7 of them are highlighted at a given time. When I scroll through the list, the 7 that are highlighted change so that not all twitter handles are available at once.

If they were all listed in the HTML, it would be easy for me to parse. Given that this isn't the case, what is the best way to get all the twitter handless in this list?

Comment: this is a little more compact and simpler to parse: https://www.producthunt.com/posts/58940/voters?offset=0&limit=25

Comment: You could call the endpoint in your browser: https://www.producthunt.com/posts/58940/voters?offset=0&limit=500

Comment: That's great! How did you get the post Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information you want you can do simple GET request to the next link:

[`https://www.producthunt.com/posts/58940/voters?offset=0&limit=1000`](https://www.producthunt.com/posts/58940/voters?offset=0&limit=1000)

Comment: @sharataka I have used Network inspector in Safari and watched all GET requests when you scroll accounts.